# php: Minus one on submit

Tags: php

I'm trying to count backwards from 10 on submit. Here's the closest I can get to what I want, but it still return an error.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {      
 $curentvalue = 10;
 $add = function ($valueToAdd) {
 $currentValue += $valueToAdd;
 getElementById('number') = $currentValue;
  }
}
```

The form looks like this (sorry about the mess):

```
<form action="main.php" method="post" target="_top">
<table id="Table1">
<tr><th>Tickets Left</th></tr>
<tr><td><span id="number">10</span></td></tr> 
<tr><td><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Plz post the error you get. I suspect it has to do w/ `$currentValue` not being accessible to your anonymous function, which can be solved like `function ($valueToAdd) use ($currentValue)`.

Comment: You cannot access the getElementById function like this: http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: Sounds to me like php and javascript is mixded here.

Answer (score 0):

This code is some kind of combination of JavaScript and PHP. This won't work.

**EDIT:**
Okay.. for example:

PHP

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['value']) {
    $_SESSION['value'] = 10;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SESSION['value'] > 0) {      
    $_SESSION['value']--;
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="main.php" method="post" target="_top">
<table id="Table1">
<tr><th>Tickets Left</th></tr>
<tr><td><span id="number"><?php echo $_SESSION['value']; ?></span></td></tr> 
<tr><td><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Or am I missing something? :)

Comment: You're right, but this answer isn't very helpful. Maybe suggest an alternative?

Comment: This is not an answer at all. It should have been a comment. I suggest you remove this "answer", David.

Comment: Sorry, but at the moment I couldn't add comment... I edited my answer, but it's difficult to provide an applicable answer..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you pass a value to your main.php when you submit your form. That is relatively easy to realize and every user can count down by itself

php part:

```
$num = (isset($_REQUEST['curNum']) ? $_REQUEST['curNum'] : 10);
```

and then in your form

```
<form action="main.php?curNum=<?php echo ($num-1); ?>" method="post" target="_top">
    <table id="Table1">
        <tr><th>Tickets Left</th></tr>
        <tr><td><span id="number"><?php echo $num; ?></span></td></tr> 
        <tr><td><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```